# Set a Boolean to active or inactive present in drop down menu in a view page containing a list of users

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am a beginner to programming and Here is my DAO file for a simple login application with update and delete methods, there are separate servlet files for both update and delete methods and I can perform the same with no issues, I was asked to add a boolean column to the table with **true** value indicating the **user** is active and vice versa.

I know the code referring to the  boolean functionality is wrong. I hope I could get some help. the accessor methods for boolean values are written in another file. I have searched all over the internet and even this site, but couldn't figure this out for two days now.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class UserDao {

//connection to jdbc mysql server//

public static Connection getConnection(){
    Connection conn=null;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName="mylogin";
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName="root";
    String dbPassword="admin";
       try{  
            Class.forName(driver);  
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName,userName,dbPassword);  
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            }  
        return conn;  
    }  

   //* block to update the user details present inside a table in DB *//

   public static int update(User e){  
        int status=0;  
        try{  
            Connection conn=UserDao.getConnection();  
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE UDATA SET username=?,password=?,address=?,phone=?,email=? where id=?");  
            System.out.println("UPDATE UDATA SET username="+e.getName()+",password="+e.getPassword()+",address="+e.getAddress()+",phone="+e.getPhone()+",email="+e.getEmail()+" where id="+e.getId());

            ps.setString(1,e.getName());  
            ps.setString(2,e.getPassword());  
            ps.setString(3,e.getAddress());  
            ps.setString(4,e.getPhone());  
            ps.setString(5,e.getEmail());
            ps.setInt(6,e.getId());  

            status=ps.executeUpdate();  

            conn.close();  
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  

        return status;  
    }  

    // code for performing deletion process//

     public static int delete(int id){  
            int status=0;  
            try{  
                Connection conn=UserDao.getConnection();  
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM udata where id=?");  
                ps.setInt(1,id);  
                status=ps.executeUpdate();  

                conn.close();  
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  

            return status;  
        }  

   //code to perform the boolean operation //

   public static boolean userStatus(){
         int id=0;
         int status=0;
         boolean active=true;
         try{
                Connection conn=UserDao.getConnection();  
                PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END FROM udata;");
                PreparedStatement ps1=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE udata where id=? and status=?"); 
                ps.setBoolean(1, active);
                ps.setInt(2, id);
                status=ps.executeUpdate();

        }

        return active;
     }
```

> Here is the setter and getter methods of the parameters. There is a similar file for **Users** This one only involves **Admin credentials**

```
     public class Admin {

private int id;  
private String adName,adPassword;  
private static boolean userStatus;
public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
public String getName() {  
    return adName;  
}  
public void setName(String name) {  
    this.adName = name;  
}  
public String getPassword() {  
    return adPassword;  
}  
public void setPassword(String password) {  
    this.adPassword = password;  
}  
public static boolean isUserStatus(){
    return userStatus; 
    }
public void setUserStatus(boolean active){
    Admin.userStatus=true;
}
}
```

Comment: "the boolean functionality is wrong" is not a good question. Provide more detail as to what you want to achieve and what the actual problem is.

Comment: @JimmyB  
I need to fetch the status of the user (Active/inactive) from a table in DB and change the status to vice versa using boolean function and update the same in the DB via a Query. Any help would be appreciated. I am a rookie.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it looks that in  your userStatus() method you are setting the params in wrong preparedstatement

Change

```
ps.setBoolean(1, active);
ps.setInt(2, id);
```

to

```
ps1.setBoolean(1, active);
ps1.setInt(2, id);
```

But I am still confused why are you setting params for your select query?
Also why you are not executing it to get the result set?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Has the initialization of the variables above is correct? Upon registration of a new user the 'Status' column holding the boolean value is set default to **Zero** (which is active state of the user) I need to retrieve that from the DB and change it to _inactive_ if that option is chosen from the drop down menu.

Comment: Not sure about your logic.. but to say I could get is in your userStatus method you should first try to fetch the status from udata and then store that to a boolean and then pass this as a parameter to your update query.

Comment: Well, that's a start for me. I am new to programming and to this site, appreciate your tolerance. Still trying to get hold of the basics as I'm self learning.

Comment: Grt8.. Pls vote +1 for the answer if you feel it helped you and accept the answer.